# Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in 'E:\frontend\node_modules\@mui\styled-engine'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui

I am trying to import a box component from `@mui/material/Box`. I have installed Material-UI 5 using the following command `npm i @mui/material`.
But this error is occurring, `Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in 'E:\frontend\node_modules\@mui\styled-engine'`

Here is my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function WhiteSpace() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 200 }}>
      <Box
        component="div"
        sx={{
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
          my: 2,
          bgcolor: 'background.paper',
        }}
      >
        White Space Nowrap. White Space Nowrap.
      </Box>
      <Box
        component="div"
        sx={{
          whiteSpace: 'normal',
          my: 2,
          bgcolor: 'background.paper',
        }}
      >
        White Space Normal. White Space Normal.
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: What are the contents of your `package.json` file?

Comment: run in shell: `npm install @emotion/react`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` are peer dependencies of many `mui` packages, ie `@mui/material`. This gives us more freedom over which emotion version we would like to use, but does mean we must install the dependencies ourselves.

```sh
npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Comment: Why do we need to do this? Shouldn't material ui install all of its dependencies without my help?

Comment: Its a good point, the community is actively discussing the [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/22435), there are tradeoffs both ways.

Comment: Might be good to mention this in the getting started docs.

Comment: @blimpse the docs are [open source](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/main/docs/introduction.mdx), feel free to create a PR

Comment: this is messed up since both emotion and mui have a lot of exports with the same name, but cannot be used mixed. I lost quite some time figuring this out

Answer (score 4):

use

```
npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

to install **@emotion/react** then it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

One of my friend faced the same issue couple of days ago, the solution is as follows:

Step 1: npm i @emotion/react
Step 2: It will give same error with different dependency name, install it with npm and your app will run.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the dependency `@emotion/react` is out of package.json somehow.
So try to run `npm install @emotion/react --save`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I try with your suggestion but still occurring same error.